# Using a string to represent the criteria for an if function in VBA

Tags: string, vba, excel, if-statement

I was hoping someone will have an answer to this. I don't think it is possible but what I am trying to do is set up an if function using a string as the criteria. For example:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    stNumerator = .Cells(6, 3).Value
    stDenominator = .Cells(6, 4).Value

    If .Cells(7, 3) = "x" Then
        stCriteria = stNumerator & " >0"
    End If

    If .Cells(8, 4) = "x" Then
        stCriteria = stCriteria & " and " & stDenominator & " <>0"
    End If

    If stCriteria Then
         .Cells(1, 1) = stNumerator / stDenominator
    End If
```

So `stCriteria` should equal `stNumerator > 0 and stDenominator <>0`

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be achieved using `Application.Evaluate`

Here is an example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim stCriteria1 As String, stCriteria2 As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")            
        stNumerator = .Cells(6, 3).Value
        stDenominator = .Cells(6, 4).Value

        If .Cells(7, 3) = "x" Then stCriteria1 = stNumerator & " >0"
        If .Cells(8, 4) = "x" Then stCriteria2 = stDenominator & " <>0"

        If stCriteria1 <> "" And stCriteria2 <> "" Then
            If Application.Evaluate(stCriteria1) And _
            Application.Evaluate(stCriteria2) Then
                 .Cells(1, 1) = stNumerator / stDenominator
            End If
        ElseIf stCriteria1 <> "" Then
            If Application.Evaluate(stCriteria1) Then
                 .Cells(1, 1) = stNumerator / stDenominator
            End If
        ElseIf stCriteria2 <> "" Then
            If Application.Evaluate(stCriteria2) Then
                 .Cells(1, 1) = stNumerator / stDenominator
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So hard to search for this question on google -- all you get are threads about string comparisons. Thanks for this.